# Varnish: Always server graced "expired" content

Tags: caching, varnish

I have a question regarding about Varnish serving expired "graced" items. Suppose the following scenario:

- My backend takes 5 seconds to generate index.php
- I set my beresp ttl to 1 minute
- My beresp grace to 1 hour.

When the first client fetches index.php he will be waiting for 5 seconds. Because there's no cached index.php item, the client will wait until the backend server generates the content.

For the following minute, the next clients will not wait at all for index.php, the cached version will be served.

After the minute passes, the following client will wait again 5 seconds. (All subsequent requests in this 5 seconds window will get the cached content due to the 1 hour grace period).

Rather than letting the client wait 5 seconds while the content is generated, is it possible for Varnish to serve the expired (graced) index.php while varnish fetches the new content? This way index.php will be updated always every 1 minute without making the clients wait.

**Update**

I found this: http://lassekarstensen.wordpress.com/2012/10/11/varnish-trick-serve-stale-content-while-refetching/

Seems a bit ugly to me though.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know this isn't possible in the current stable version, BUT Varnish 4 will support background fetches. You can find more information about Varnish 4 in the keynote [slides](https://www.varnish-cache.org/sites/default/files/01-VUG8-Keynote-phk-Varnish4-what-why_0.pdf) of VUG8.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be right Arjan.

From: https://www.varnish-cache.org/releases/varnish-cache-4.0.0-tp1

Full streaming support, including asynchronous backend fetches. This enables Varnish to serve stale objects while it is fetching or revalidating objects from the backend.